# Add Circled logo to magento 2 header

Tags: html, css, magento, header

Here is my current layout

[image]

I need to add a new logo which has a circle shape. The logo div overflows down from the header block and having a higher stack order (z index) .The height of the header block must not be changed after adding the new logo. so the new layout will be as follow:

[image]

I know how to edit the header template (adding/editing css and html) by creating new new module in magento.

However what I need is the html and css code to make logo overflow without pushing down the whole header block. It that possible?

Html Code

```
<header class="page-header">
    <div class="header content">
        <span data-action="toggle-nav" class="action nav-toggle"><span>Toggle Nav</span></span>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2 no-pad-left super-logo">
        <div class="main-logo">
            <h1 class="logo">
                <a href="example.com">
                    <img src="https://www.example.com/logo.png" alt="ex" width="1" height="1">
                </a>
            </h1>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="block block-search col-lg-5 col-lg-offset col-sm-9">
    <div class="block block-title"><strong>Search</strong></div>
    <div class="block block-content">
        .
        .
        .
    </div>
</div>

<ul class="compare wrapper"><li class="item link compare" data-bind="scope: 'compareProducts'" data-role="compare-products-link">
    .
    .
</ul>

<ul class="header links">
....
</ul>
```

Comment: Try to put your logo picture as a background image of your `<div class="main-logo">` instead of `<img>` element and the picture size should not affect other element after that.

Comment: I tried it. Same problem exist

Comment: Yes, You can do it with css please do the following steps                 
  .page-header {
    position: relative;
}                                                                                                                .logo {  position: absolute;
    top: -32px;
    z-index: 1;                                                                                               
    }

Comment: It works great. Exactly what I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were most of the way to an answer with your suggestion of using the z-index property.

```css
header { width: 100%; background-color: #660066; color: #ffffff; position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 0 }

.main-logo { border-radius: 50%; background-color: #330033; z-index: 10; position: fixed; top: 5px; left: 5px; }

.action { margin: 1em 0 0.5em 8em }

.block-search { margin: 0 0 0.5em 8em }
```

```html
<header class="page-header">
    <div class="header content">
        <span data-action="toggle-nav" class="action nav-toggle"><span>Toggle Nav</span></span>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2 no-pad-left super-logo">
        <div class="main-logo">
            <h1 class="logo">
                <a href="example.com">
                    <img src="https://www.example.com/logo.png" alt="example" width="1" height="1">
                </a>
            </h1>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="block block-search col-lg-5 col-lg-offset col-sm-9">
    <div class="block block-title"><strong>Search</strong></div>
    <div class="block block-content">
        .
        .
        .
    </div>
</div>
    </header>

<ul class="compare wrapper"><li class="item link compare" data-bind="scope: 'compareProducts'" data-role="compare-products-link">
    .
    .
</ul>

<ul class="header links">
....
</ul>
```